# How do I resolve "no connection is known" for FreeSwan VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn

```
cannot respond to IPsec SA request because no connection is known for 111.111.111.111:4500:17/1701...222.222.222.222:40389[@laptop.our.windows.domain]:17/1701===0
```

I've spent hours trying to figure this out in the past with no success.  I've never even found a good explanation of how the parts of the network notation map to the ipsec config file.  The error message comes from a Windows XP machine.  It used to connect fine using a modem-mode cellular device, but is now using one that operates by ethernet-over-USB.  I've had as little luck connecting an OS X 10.6 machine behind a commercial router.